# Where is Visual Studio 2015 local help for System.Web.MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I installed everything remotely relevant to C#/ASP.Net development in my local help content. However, when I edit CSHTML files, put cursor on Label in @Html.Label and press F1 the help topic that comes up is an online content. When I open it in the browser it becomes clear this help topic is under **System.Web.Mvc.Html >LabelExtensions Class > LabelExtensions Methods**

When I look at Contents tab in local help under .NET Framework 4.6 and 4.5.NET Framework Class Library()\System.Web Namespaces() **System.Web.MVC** doesn't exist there. What I have is **System.Web.ModelBinding** and the one below is **System.Web.Profile** namespace

Can anyone explain this? Can Visual Studio 2015 local help for MVC be downloaded locally at all?

Note that I did find 2 posts about this issue but neither has an answer:

[MVC 6 integrated help missing in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382485/mvc-6-integrated-help-missing-in-visual-studio-2015)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5d79acd8-9b42-47a0-9bd5-50ca721e62c8/visual-studio-2015-f1-help-doesnt-work?forum=visualstudiogeneral